# Rails 3 - how to get data through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, has-many, has-one

Whole afternoon I am struggling with the getting data from associations. I have these 3 models:

**User**

```
  has_many :user_cars
```

**Car**

```
  has_one :user_cars
```

**UserCar**

```
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :user
```

The table **user_cars** has the columns

```
user_id
car_id
```

I have in a view the statement of all cars and to every car I would like to print, if the currently logged-in user has the car.

I am trying to do it as:

```
<% @user_cars.car.name%>
```

But this gives me the error

```
undefined method `car' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x0000012edc14a8>
```

I would like to ask you - have I a fault already in associations or in the view?

**EDIT:**

```
<% @cars.each_with_index do |car, i|%> #loop through all cars in the system
  #in the every loop I would like to print, if the user has this one

  <% @user_cars.each do |c| %> #through the loop I can get it, but I think is not efficient 
    <li><%= c.car.name %></li>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is @user_cars initialized? It seems you are taking User#user_cars as its value. Try

```
<% @user_cars.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= c.car.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

And you could also use `has_many :through` to simplify the connection:

```
# User model
has_many :user_cars
has_many :cars, :through => :user_cars
```

Then all the cars belongs to the user can be access via User#cars.

If you want to check whether a given car belongs to the user, you could first get all cars owned by the user (remember to add the above lines to user model first):

```
@owned_cars = current_user.cars.all
```

And then check if a given car is included in this list:

```
<% @cars.each_with_index do |car, i|%> #loop through all cars in the system
  <% if @owned_cars.include?(car) %>
    <%= car.name %> is owned by the user
  <% else %>
    <%= car.name %> is not owned by the user
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ZelluX is correct. @user_cars is a collection of Cars, so you need to iterate over the collection by using the `each` method.

Comment: Thank you guys, this partially solve my problem - partially because, of 2 loops. I updated my original post - look at that, please. What you helped me - that works. But now I have the situation, when I have loop in the loop - and I would like to ask you, if is any more efficient way...

Comment: @user984621 Could you please post how is user_cars get initialized?

Comment: @ZelluX sure, this is it: `@ user_cars = UserCar.where(:user_id => current_user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Check the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html